# How to Copy a Struct with a string Set to ByValTStr

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a struct that looks like the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 17, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    [FieldOffset(0)] public string myString;
}
```

However, when I copy the struct using `Marshal.Copy(...)` to test it out the string prints as if null or empty.

```
MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct { myString = "Hello, World!" };

byte[] bytes = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct))];

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(myStruct, GCHandleType.Pinned);

Marshal.Copy(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bytes, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)));

handle.Free();

handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);

myStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyStruct>(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());

handle.Free();
```

`myStruct.myString` reads as null.
Am I missing something (probably obvious)?

Thanks,

Comment: What should it print as? The ByVatTStr applies to the unmanaged representation of the structure. The managed `myString` is null.

Comment: You don't show how you're using `Marshal.Copy`, but none of its overloads do anything with complex types anyway, so it can't do anything with marshaling attributes -- it's just a flat copy. `Marshal.StructureToPtr` does marshal. Note that if you want to literally copy a 17-byte character array and nothing else, wrapping it with a struct is not exactly the simplest approach.

Comment: Sorry, I just typed an example and it was poor. What I'm trying to do is have a string in a struct and copy that struct to bytes and move it around (possibly over the network) and then turn those bytes back into a struct at a later time.

I will update the question.

Comment: Yeah, don't. The marshaler is for interfacing with unmanaged code. It is not a general binary serializer; the built in remoting features (though deprecated now), gRPC and Protobuf are, along simpler serialization mechanisms like JSON, and other modern approaches like `System.IO.Pipelines`. Using the marshaler is neither simpler *nor* faster, regardless of whether you're defining your own protocol or trying to adhere to an existing one. Even hand-rolled code with `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` is more robust and likely not much slower.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I have the right version of .net for that.

Comment: `Pipelines` is only for .NET Core, native remoting is only for .NET Framework, the rest of the things I named are available for both. In no version of .NET is the marshaler the go-to thing for binary serialization.